# Search subitem in listview and remove item

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am trying to do a compare with a double number inputted by the user compared to a subitem contained in listview. I have tried the following code but it removes the wrong values and I can not seem to get it to work. I want to compare

```
ListView1.Items(index).SubItems(1).Text <= spread_less_then_input.Text
```

I am not sure if it is a problem with the code of the fact that the numbers are in string format. here is the code I am currently trying

```
If spread_less_then_input.Text() <> "" And (ListView1.Items.Count <> 0) Then
    For index As Integer = ListView1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If ListView1.Items(index).SubItems(1).Text <= spread_less_then_input.Text Then
            ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(index)
        End If
    Next index
End If
```

Comment: First, set `Option Strict On`.  A listview can only ever hold text/strings treating them as numbers without converting leads to poor results.  `"9"` will always evaluate higher than say `"1234"`.  Strings are not numbers.  It also sounds like a DataGridView would be more appropriate.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to convert string to double
            For index As Integer = ListView1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                Dim userinput As Double
                Dim subitem As Double
                userinput = CDbl(Val(spread_greater_then_input.Text()))
                subitem = CDbl(Val(ListView1.Items(index).SubItems(1).Text)) '// Val do hard work(ListView1.Items(index).SubItems(3).Text, result1)
                If userinput >= subitem Then
                    ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(index)
                End If
            Next index
        End If